# MySQL does not apply one-to-many relationship

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, relational-database, primary-key

I have the 2 dimension tables and 1 fact table. They look like this:

- Dimension table 1: Investor_DM

| Investor_nr | Investor_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Jack |
| 2 | Kelly |

- Dimension table 2: Company_DM

| Company_nr | Company_name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Apple |
| 2 | Microsoft |

- Fact table: Positions

| Company_nr | Investor_nr | InvestmentDate | InvestmentSize |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 2022-jan-02 | $1,000 |
| 2 | 1 | 2022-feb-03 | $1,500 |
| 1 | 2 | 2022-jun-02 | $7,000 |
| 2 | 2 | 2022-jul-03 | $7,500 |

I assigned Investor_nr and Company_nr as PK's in their respective dimension tables, and assigned FK's in the fact table in which I refer to the PK's.

What I want is when I look for data WHERE Investor_nr = '1', I only get the investments in the fact table of investor 1, etc. However, I still get all investments even though I have created one-to-many relationships between the tables. Same goes for the company dimension table.

This is my

```
SELECT *
FROM Positions
WHERE Investor_nr = '1'
;
```

query:

I would hope that if I SELECT * from all 3 tables, the Investor_nr's on each row correspond between the fact and dimension table, but this is not the case. Same goes for Company_nr.

What am I missing here? Am I using the wrong query, or are my relationships wrong?
I tried multiple queries, sometimes only on 1 table and sometimes 2 or 3 tables, but I always get data from investors I did not filter on.

Thanks!

Comment: SQL doesn't follow foreign keys automatically. You have to write explicit JOIN queries to do that.

Comment: @Barmar Thanks! But what is the added value of the relationship, if I have to explicitly JOIN them in each query? Seems like I am telling SQL the same thing twice, but maybe I understand it incorrectly.

Comment: It does 2 automatic things: An index is created when you declare the foreign key, and it checks that the value actually exists on the referenced table to ensure referential integrity.

Comment: You can also use options like `ON DELETE CASCADE`. So if you delete an investor, all the positions of that investor are deleted automatically.

Comment: > "Seems like I am telling SQL the same thing twice". Sort of, but the relationship is a "constraint" to protect the data and a join is to select related data. You always want to protect the data but you might not always want to select all the data.

Comment: If the column names are the same in the two tables, you can use `NATURAL JOIN` to have it figure out the join condition automatically.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I should have known this but your explanations really made it clear.